# Check username availability with jquery validation plugin (servlet and jsp)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-validate

I an using jquery validator plugin to validate my registration form. However, when I tried to check if an username is in the database, it does not work. Can anyone help take a look at my codes and let me know what I did wrong? It always shows user already exist even when the username is not in database.

I have tried the methods from

> > [jQuery Validate remote method usage to check if username already
> >     exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577120/jquery-validate-remote-method-usage-to-check-if-username-already-exists) and  [JQuery Remote Validation not displaying Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528104/jquery-remote-validation-not-displaying-error)

but it still doesn't work.

My registration jquery function:

```
   $().ready(function() {

        $.validator.addMethod('uniqueUsername', function(value) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/TBS-war/RegisterServlet.java',
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json'

            });
        });

        //Validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#registrationForm").validate({
            // Set rules
            rules: {
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    uniqueUsername: true
                    /*remote: {
                        url: "http://localhost:8080/TBS-war/RegisterServlet.java",
                        type: "post",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: {
                            'username': $('#username').val()
                        }
                    }*/
                },
                password: {
                    required: true
                },
                confirmPassword: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },
                contact: {
                    required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                address: {
                    required: true
            }},

            // Set messages
            messages: {
                username: {
                    required: "* This field is required",
                    uniqueUsername: "* User already exist"
                    //remote: "* User already exist"
                },
                password: {
                    required: "* This field is required"
                },
                confirmPassword: {
                    required: "* This field is required",
                    equalTo: "* Please enter the same password as above"
                },
                contact: {
                    required: "* This field is required"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "* This field is required",
                    email: "* Please enter a valid email"
                },
                address: {
                    required: "* This field is required"
            }},
```

My servlet file:

```
@EJB
private TBSManagerBeanRemote tBSManagerBean;


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        String username = request.getParameter("username");

        if (tBSManagerBean.userExist(username)) {
            out.print("{\"valid\" : false }");
            json.put("valid", false);
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        else {
            out.print("{\"valid\" : true }");
            json.put("valid", true);
            System.out.println("true");
        }
    }
```

Comment: When using the `.addMethod()` method, you must `return` a `true` or `false` depending on whether you want to pass or fail validation.  Your custom method returns nothing.  See examples:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Comment: However, the most proper way to do this is through the `remote` method.   And you do not need the `data` option because the value of the field is already sent.  See examples:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: I tried the remote method but when using the remote method, the validation does not work

Comment: And may I know how can I compare the values returned by the servlet in the jquery? I tried to find it online but don't really understand how it was done